# How to install and run pnpm?

Tags: nodejs

When I try to run `pnpm start` after installed pnpm with this method: `npm install -g pnpm`, the result giving error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at: https://vsys.host/how-to/how-to-install-pnpm-on-ubuntu-22-04

> ##### Step 1: Update Package Lists
>
> Before installing PNPM, you should update the package lists on your
> Ubuntu system. This can be done using the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> The command will display the process of updating the package lists on
> your system.
>
> ##### Step 2: Install Node.js and NPM
>
> PNPM is built on top of Node.js and NPM, so we will need to install
> these first. Run the following command to install Node.js and NPM on
> your system:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
> ```
>
> This command installs both Node.js and NPM on your system.
>
> ##### Step 3: Install PNPM
>
> Now that we have Node.js and NPM installed, we can install PNPM using
> NPM. Run the following command to install PNPM:
>
> ```
> sudo npm install -g pnpm
> ```
>
> This command installs PNPM globally on your system.
>
> ##### Step 4: Verify PNPM Installation
>
> To verify that PNPM is installed correctly, you can run the following
> command to check the version of PNPM:
>
> ```
> pnpm -v
> ```
>
> This command will display the version number of PNPM that is installed
> on your system.